# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException Error: jpa 2 + hibernate - Native Query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm getting the above error when I'm trying to update sphinx real time indexes. Since sphinx uses a database very close to mysql, I'm trying to use entity manager to update indexes. But sphinxql isn't a full mysql database so if I use entitymanager.merge method the sql generated isn't understood by sphinxql. Therefore, I decided to use createNativeQuery to insert new indices or delete indices from the Real Time Index. However, I'm getting the exception in the title when I invoke .executeUpdate method of createNativeQuery.

This is my Dao:

```
public interface RTIndexGeoDao {

    public boolean deleteIndex(long id);

    public boolean insertIndex(long id, long agentActivityId, long agentId, double latitude, double longitude);
}
```

This is my Implementation of Dao:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository(value = "rtIndexGeoDao")
public class JPARTIndexDao implements RTIndexGeoDao {

    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "rtIndexPU")
    public void setRtIndexEntityManager(EntityManager em)
    {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public boolean deleteIndex(long id) {
        //This is to update our geodistance index
        try
        {
            this.em.createNativeQuery("delete from rt_geo where agent_agent_id = ?1").setParameter(1, id).executeUpdate();


            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean insertIndex(long id, long agentActivityId, long agentId,
            double latitude, double longitude) {
        try
        {
            this.em.createNativeQuery("insert into rt_geo(id, agent_activity_id, agent_agent_id, latitude, longitude) values(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5)")
            .setParameter(1, id)
            .setParameter(2, agentActivityId)
            .setParameter(3, agentId)
            .setParameter(4, latitude)
            .setParameter(5, longitude).executeUpdate();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my RTIndexManager:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springtest.mavenspringapp.repository.RTIndexGeoDao;

@Component
@Transactional
public class SphinxRTIndexManagerImpl implements SphinxRTIndexManager {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private RTIndexGeoDao rtIndexGeoDao;

    public boolean deleteIndex(long id) {
        return rtIndexGeoDao.deleteIndex(id);
    }

    public boolean insertIndex(long id, long agentActivityId, long agentId,
            double latitude, double longitude) {
        return rtIndexGeoDao.insertIndex(id, agentActivityId, agentId, latitude, longitude);
    }

}
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="rtIndexPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    </persistence-unit>
```

This is the controller:

```
@Autowired
    private SphinxRTIndexManager rtIndexManager;
private AgentActivity createActivity(Agent agent, double latitude, double longitude, String agentActivityDescription)
    {
//Steps to update indexes
        boolean deleteEntry = rtIndexManager.deleteIndex(agent.getAgentId());
        if (!deleteEntry) return null;
```

UPDATE: I'm posting my applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
<bean id="rtIndexEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="rtIndexDataSource"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>                             
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="rtIndexPU"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="rtIndexTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="rtIndexEntityManagerFactory"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

I have another persistence unit and every manager, dao, etc works. But when I use createNativeQuery.executeUpdate on entitymanager whose persistenceContext is rtIndexPU, this exception occurs:

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

I've searched at every question available on the internet, but cannot have this issue solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your Spring configuration as well

Comment: Do you have <tx:annotation-driven/> in your configuration anywhere?

Comment: Yes I do, but I forgot to post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have two transaction managers in your code, the problem is most likely that your `SphinxRTIndexManagerImpl` is not using the correct one (or any).

You should change the code to:

```
@Component
@Transactional("rtIndexTransactionManager")
public class SphinxRTIndexManagerImpl implements SphinxRTIndexManager {

}
```

Also you have to configure the second transaction manager (rtIndexTransactionManager) for working with annotations, by doing:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="rtIndexTransactionManager"/>
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is! Thanks for your help geoand. I hope this help other people having the same issue. Most of the answers I found indicate to use beginTransaction before the transaction. In other words, suggest to manually handle the transaction

Comment: @JorgeCespedes Glad tp help!